# Is there is any way to check efficiently if any key is missing in the provided jsonObject?

Tags: java, json

I know how to check if a particular key is present or not in the provided `jsonStr` using `jsonStr.has("key")`. To check for multiple key-existence, I have to check them separately. Is there any method in Java so that I can check efficiently for a list of keys if any of them does not exist in the provided `jsonStr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the keys that needs to be found to a list/set. Then you can use

```
myKeyList.stream().allMatch(key->jsonStr.has(key))
```

to see if all keys are present in JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

Basically... No.

Most of these JsonObject implementations use a `java.util.Map` in which the JSON properties are kept. Mainly because a Map only has one method `boolean containsKey(Object key);`, most *if not all* implementations do not have a method to check for multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of [`JsonObject`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonObject.java), it uses `LinkedTreeMap` to store all the elements:

```
private final LinkedTreeMap<String, JsonElement> members =
  new LinkedTreeMap<String, JsonElement>();
```

It also has a `keySet()` method, which will return `Set<String>` but the implemention uses **exactly the same function (`find()`)** as the `has()` function.

So you have the following options:

1. Iterate over you list of keys you want to check for existence in the `JSONObject`
2. Create your own deserializer, which will create `Set<String>` of keys present in the deserialized string, which you will be able to effectively compare with your `Set<String>` of wanted keys.